# How to calculate distance between two values from two different 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two `bool[5,5]` arrays which look like this:

1st:

```
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
```

2nd:

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

What I have to do is simple calculating distance between `1` from 1st array and `1` from the 2nd one. I had multiple tries to solve this problem, but I can't solve this.

The result should looks like this:

```
4+3+2+1+0
0+0+0+0+0
0+0+0+0+0
0+0+0+0+0
0+1+0+3+0
```

Let me name arrays: `first[,]` and `second[,]`

There are fiew conditions:

1. `if (first[i,j] == true && second[i,j] == true) distance[i,j] = 0`
2. `if (first[i,j] == false) distance[i,j] = 0`
3. `if (first[i,j] == true)` then I have to calculate distance between closest `1` from `second[,]` eg. There are `1` in `first[1,4]` and `first[3,4]` and there is `1` in `second[0,4]` (there was mistake), so it means that `distance[3,4] = 3 - 0` (because of second array's dimensions).

This is main method to calculate:

```
` static public int findPicture()
    {
        int[,] m = new int[testBitmap.GetLength(0), 
        testBitmap.GetLength(1)];

        foreach (var picture in pictures)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    if (testBitmap[i,j] == true)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            i = i + 1;
                        } while (picture.Value[i,j] != true);

                        m[i,j] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            var total = 0;

            for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++)
                {
                    total += m[a, b];
                }
            }

            return total;
        }



        return -1;
    }`
```

It was my closest version to solve.

I would be very greatful if you could give some advices to solve this trivial problem.

Comment: Please show your code so we can see what you have tried so far. Also, you may want to elaborate why the result is whatever you have posted so people do not have to figure it out (not the whole thing but just a few).

Comment: Share the code you already tried and why the outcome didn't satisfy your need.

Comment: I can't understand the last line. It seems to me that there should be 0+0+0+0+0 (instead of 0+1+0+3+0). Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @SergeBogatyrev corrected

Comment: Do you want lines to wrap? Also, how do you treat the all-zero condition in the second matrix?

Comment: Define "distance". Is it based on a 2D plane or is it limited to the same row or what?

Comment: @itsme86 its limited to same row

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
static int[,] BuildDistanceArray(bool[,] array1, bool[,] array2)
{
    if (array1.GetLength(0) != array2.GetLength(0) || array1.GetLength(1) != array2.GetLength(1))
        throw new Exception("Array sizes must match.");

    int[,] distance = new int[array1.GetLength(0), array1.GetLength(1)];

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.GetLength(0); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.GetLength(1); ++j)
        {
            distance[i, j] = array1[i, j] ? GetDistance(array2, i, j) : 0;
        }
    }

    return distance;
}

static int GetDistance(bool[,] array, int row, int column)
{
    int maxColumn = array.GetLength(1);
    int distance = 0;

    bool again;
    do
    {
        again = false;

        if (column - distance >= 0)
        {
            if (array[row, column - distance])
                return distance;
            again = true;
        }
        if (column + distance < maxColumn)
        {
            if (array[row, column + distance])
                return distance;
            again = true;
        }

        distance++;
    } while (again);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives the results you're looking for and it works for any size array.

Answer (score 0):

This function calculates distance between 2 rows converted to int32. It's written in java, so some minor transformation will be required.

```
int distance(int x, int y) {
    int count = Integer.bitCount(x);
    int totalDist = 0;
    for (int offset = 0; offset < 5 && x != 0; offset++) {

        x = x ^ (x & (y << offset) & 0b11111);
        x = x ^ (x & (y >>> offset));

        int nextCount = Integer.bitCount(x);
        totalDist += (count - nextCount) * offset;
        count = nextCount;
    }
    return totalDist;
}
```